# Firebase JSON structure not plugging into widget function

Tags: javascript, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I know this is probably a common question but I had issues getting any solutions to work with my use case. I have a calendar widget I have forked on Codepen made using JS. I want to replace the default data with my Firebase database but the JSON structure is different and breaks the Calendar function. My JSON in Firebase is as follows:

```
    {
  "Events" : {
    "cool event" : {
      "calendar" : "Other",
      "color" : "yellow",
      "date" : "2017-01-13",
      "eventName" : "new"
    }
  },
```

The original method that the widget received data was as so:

```
var data = [
    { eventName: 'Lunch Meeting w/ Mark', calendar: 'Work', color: 'orange', date: '2014-02-08' },]
```

How can I format either my data or modify the function to accept my data structure? Keep in mind, Firebase does not allow a simple array and stores them as objects...

Here is a CodePen: http://codepen.io/Auzy/pen/OWJxqO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to transform your data to an array of the required format

For example

```js
var firebase = {
  "Events" : {
    "cool event" : {
      "calendar" : "Other",
      "color" : "yellow",
      "date" : "2017-01-13",
      "eventName" : "new"
    }
  }
};

var data = [];
for(event in firebase.Events){
  data.push(firebase.Events[event])
}

console.log(data)
```

---

**Update**

Firebase api is asynchronous, so you need to wait for the data (*using the `.once('value').then(..)`*) to return and then transform the data (*which you actually do not need since firebase provides an iterator*) and then initialize the calendar.

So you need to change your code to

```
var stuff = firebase.database().ref().child("Events");
var data = [];
stuff.once('value').then(function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function(event){
        data.push( event.val() );
    })
    var calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', data);
});
```

(*and remove the initialization from the bottom of the code as it has been inserted in the callback*)

Comment: @JediCoder updated answer with solution (*has been tested on the codepen*)